# Find an expression to $ \operatorname{Res}(g,\frac{z_0}{a})$ with $\operatorname{Res}(f,z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, residue-calculus

> Given $z_0$ singular point of $f(z)$ and let $a>0$ real number, setting $g(z)=f(az)$ find an expression to $\operatorname{Res}(g,\frac{z_0}{a})$ with $\operatorname{Res}(f,z_0)$

My attempt

$Res(g,\frac{z_0}{a})=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|\xi-\frac{z_0}{a}|=\epsilon}g(\xi)d\xi=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|\xi-\frac{z_0}{a}|=\epsilon}f(a\xi)d\xi=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|\xi-z_0|=\epsilon}\frac{1}{a}f(\xi)d\xi=\frac{1}{a}Res(f,z_0)$

Not sure if this is the right answer

Comment: You could also write the Laurent-expansion of $f$ at $z_0$ and then work it out, to get the Laurent-expansion of $g$

Comment: Yea you are right,but can you tell me if this is the right answer?

Comment: Yes, it is correct (an "a" is missing in the last integral: you should integrate over the circle of radius $a \epsilon$).

Comment: Easiest to use the definition of the residue, using l’Hopital’s rule as appropriate. You stated $z_0$ is a singular point, but I imagine you meant it’s a pole of some order.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Desperado's comment, assume that the function $f(z)$ has a Laurent expansion at $z=z_{0}$.

Then   $$ f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_{n} (z-z_{0})^{n}.$$

Replacing $z$ with $az$, $a >0$, we get $$g(z) = f(az) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_{n} (az-z_{0})^{n}  = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a^{n} b_{n} \left(z-\frac{z_{0}}{a} \right)^{n}.$$  Therefore, $$\operatorname{Res}\left[ g(z), \frac{z_{0}}{a}\right] = a^{-1}b_{-1} = \frac{1}{a} \, \operatorname{Res} \left[f(z), z_{0} \right].$$